# Replacing white space differently depending on number of spaces in a shell

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a strangely formatted dataset based, of weather data nonetheless, and I suspect that this is a job for SED.
The data as either white spaces between entries or has 2 spaces with an identifier.  I'm trying to write a shells script to take this data and turn it into a CSV file.  I used AWK to replace the spaces to commas, but then I realized that there are different numbers of spaces because someone decided to do something screwy.  As an example, I have a subset:

```
USH00011084 1897   734  3  1292  3  1972  3  1786  3  2084  3  2761  3  2753  3  2547  3  2406  3  1878  3 -9999    -9999   
USH00011084 1900 -9999    -9999     1337a 3  1936  3  2378  3  2589  3  2770  3  2872  3  2700  3  2320  3  1486  3  1100  3
USH00011084 1926 -9999     1245     1251a    1781     2240     2654     2712     2763c    2770     2110     1256a    1421   
USH00011084 1927  1209     1821     1651     2183     2467     2707     2730     2594a    2579     2081     1907      871f 3
USH00011084 1928   800b    1135     1614     1711     2218     2596     2829     2817    -9999    -9999    -9999    -9999
```

I think that I can use SED to put a comma if there's less than 5 spaces, and two commas if there are 5 spaces; however, I haven't quite figured it out.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say...

```
sed -e 's/     /,,/g' -e 's/ \+/,/g' file
```

Or, a bit cleaner:

```
sed -re 's/ {5}/,,/g' -e 's/ +/,/g' file
```

Both produce:

```
USH00011084,1897,734,3,1292,3,1972,3,1786,3,2084,3,2761,3,2753,3,2547,3,2406,3,1878,3,-9999,-9999,
USH00011084,1900,-9999,-9999,,1337a,3,1936,3,2378,3,2589,3,2770,3,2872,3,2700,3,2320,3,1486,3,1100,3
USH00011084,1926,-9999,,1245,,1251a,1781,,2240,,2654,,2712,,2763c,2770,,2110,,1256a,1421,
USH00011084,1927,1209,,1821,,1651,,2183,,2467,,2707,,2730,,2594a,2579,,2081,,1907,,,871f,3
USH00011084,1928,800b,1135,,1614,,1711,,2218,,2596,,2829,,2817,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,
```

The logic is what you mention:

- Replace 5 spaces with `,,`.
- Replace one or more spaces (the ones that still appear after the first replacement) with `,`.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using `-e` instead of `;`, or just preference ?

Comment: Also an alternative way would be to use one `s` `sed 's/ \{1,4\}/,/g'`

Comment: @User112638726 I kind of prefer `-e` because I see the code better. I assume they are exactly equivalent, but let me know if it is not the case! Also, thanks for the suggestion, I will leave it as it is now until we get some update from OP

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to dependent on count of spaces in input file then you can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1} 1' file
USH00011084,1897,734,3,1292,3,1972,3,1786,3,2084,3,2761,3,2753,3,2547,3,2406,3,1878,3,-9999,-9999
USH00011084,1900,-9999,-9999,1337a,3,1936,3,2378,3,2589,3,2770,3,2872,3,2700,3,2320,3,1486,3,1100,3
USH00011084,1926,-9999,1245,1251a,1781,2240,2654,2712,2763c,2770,2110,1256a,1421
USH00011084,1927,1209,1821,1651,2183,2467,2707,2730,2594a,2579,2081,1907,871f,3
USH00011084,1928,800b,1135,1614,1711,2218,2596,2829,2817,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999
```

**Breakup of awk command**:

```
-F '[[:blank:]]+'   # use one of more whitespace a input field separator
-v OFS=,            # use comma as output field separator
{$1=$1}             # force awk to restructure each record
```